package management with pixi: global commands not exposed
I am trying out pixi for replacing package management and condo environments. Activating a shell works fine, but I like to have some tools always available for which I think there is pixi global. I have tried to use it, but the commands are not available in the shell.
For example this one:
 pixi global install jupyter ipython --environment science --with numpy --with matplotlib

Installed just fine and the output of pixi global list gives me
Global environments as specified in '$HOME/.pixi/manifests/pixi-global.toml'
└── science 
    ├─ dependencies: jupyter 1.1.1, ipython 8.30.0, numpy 2.1.3, matplotlib 3.9.2
    └─ exposes: ipython, ipython3, jupyter

but none of the commands it lists are actually available?
How can I have those commands available upon opening the terminal, or even better, how can I best mimic a conda base environment that is available when I log on (I am on zsh but sometimes on bash as well).
for reference, I am using pixi via homebrew:
Pixi version: 0.38.0
Platform: osx-arm64


When you install Pixi using homebrew, it doesn't automatically update your path to include ~/.pixi/bin, which is necessary to make the global commands work.
You can manually update your ~/.zshrc to include ~/.pixi/bin in your PATH to invoke the pixi global command(s) from anywhere, or re-install using curl -fsSL https://pixi.sh/install.sh | zsh to have it do that for you automatically.

that did it! Thanks!
